# Let $v_1,v_2$ be vectors in $\mathbb{Q}^3$. Prove that they are linearly independent on $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if they are on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $v_1,v_2$ be vectors in $\Bbb Q^3$ (and each one of them is a vector in the $\Bbb R$-vectorial space $\Bbb R^3$ $\Bbb R$). Is it true that these vectors are linearly independent as vectors in $\Bbb Q^3$ if and only if they are linearly independent in the $\Bbb R$-vectorial space $\Bbb{R}^3$?

I tried to do it by the definition of linearly Independent (if $a_1v_1+a_2v_2 =0$ then $a_1=a_2=0$, no matter if I'm in $\Bbb Q^3$ or in $\Bbb R^3$), but I feel like the problem maybe has more ideas that I should use.

Comment: As $\Bbb Q$ is a (proper)subset of $\Bbb R$, you can prove that a linearly independent set is linearly independent in all of its subsets, this should be easy. For the converse, i'm not sure lol, suppose by contradiction that its not true, write out the definition of linear dependence and the definitionn of real nnumbers, rational numbers and irrtional numbers, you should see a connection there.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

Take your vectors $\{v_1,v_2\}\subset\mathbb{Q}^3$ and consider the $3\times2$ matrix $A=(v_1|v_2)$ with columns $v_1$ and $v_2.$ Now this matrix has linearly independent columns if and only if there is a $2\times 2$ submatrix whose determinant does not vanish. But this condition is the same whether we consider $A$ as a matrix over $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R}$ or even $\mathbb{C}.$

Answer (score 2):

First, the non-independence over $\mathbb{R}$ implies the same over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Now, if $v_1=av_2$ with $a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, then component a component we have that
a real non-zero number times a rational number is rational, i.e., $av_{2j}=v_{1j}$. But, it creates a contradiction because since some component is non-zero, $a=\frac{v_{1j}}{v{2j}}\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the following procedure for determining whether a set of $m$ vectors in $F^n$ are linearly independent: put the vectors as the columns of an $m \times n$ matrix, and then perform Gaussian elimination on that matrix to get it into row echelon form.  If you get $m$ pivots at the end, then the original vectors are linearly independent; while if you get strictly less than $m$ pivots, then the original vectors are linearly dependent.

Now in your situation, suppose you perform that procedure with scalars in $\mathbb{Q}$.  Then the Gaussian elimination you performed is also a valid Gaussian elimination with scalars in $\mathbb{R}$.  Therefore, whatever answer you get for linear independence over $\mathbb{Q}$, you will get the same answer for linear independence over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score -1):

$$p\Rightarrow q \Leftrightarrow \not \not q\Rightarrow \not p:$$
$$v_1, v_2\in \mathbb Q^3 \text{ linearly dependent on }\mathbb R^3 \Leftrightarrow \exists r\ne 0 \in \mathbb R: v_1=r\cdot v_2\Leftrightarrow \left(\underbrace{v_{1i}}_{\in \mathbb Q}=r\underbrace{v_{2i}}_{\in \mathbb Q}\right )_{1\le i\le 3}\Rightarrow r\in \mathbb Q\Rightarrow v_1, v_2 \text { linearly dependent on }\mathbb Q^3$$

$$q\Rightarrow p:$$

$$v_1, v_2\in \mathbb Q^3 \text{ linearly independent on } \mathbb R^3 \Leftrightarrow (a_1v_1+a_2v_2=0\Rightarrow a_1=a_2=0)\land 0 \in \mathbb Q\Leftrightarrow v_1,v_2 \text{ linearly independent on } \mathbb Q^3$$

$$(p\Rightarrow q \land q\Rightarrow p) \Leftrightarrow (p\Leftrightarrow q) (\therefore)$$

Comment: As this stands, it's a bit hard to read; it would be better with more explanatory text.  Also, you need to consider the special case that if $v_2 = 0$ and $v_1 \ne 0$ then $v_1, v_2$ are still linearly dependent but $v_1$ is not a scalar multiple of $v_2$.  There's also the point that some entries of $v_1$ and $v_2$ might be zero; but if you're not in the case $v_2 = 0$, then there is at least one choice of $i$ such that the argument will work.

Comment: I understand you can’t read my answer properly- you meant maybe that you don’t understand it? If you have some concerns that’s something else. The concern involving zero-vector should not bother anyone-least you since you didn’t deal with it in your own answer either. I’m not saying you should have, I’m saying lets not try to berate each other or force each other to make unnecessary changes just for the sake of getting ahead.

Comment: The proof is very badly written and despite of its length, some important arguments or quantificators are missing.

Comment: The proof is an attempt of concept and should receive recognition for its validity despite its alleged shortcomings which grace to your feedback, remain undefined. If you wanted to make the answer better you’re welcome to write your own proof in the same manner of this one. That way would really help me and anyone else to see what is “badly written” in my proof let alone the “important arguments and qualifications” missing. I don’t work in policing mathematics and since we don’t have a court of law for actions like yours, you shouldn’t either.